# owasp - invoke Depenendecy-check in jenkins-dsl-job

Tags: jenkins, owasp, jenkins-job-dsl

How can i use invoke Depenendecy-check in jenkins-job-dsl ?
[image]

I  only see example for  Publishing OWASP dependency check results. https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.dependencyCheck

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself.

```
dependencyCheck {
  odcInstallation('710')
  additionalArguments('--proxyserver x.x.x.x --proxyport 3128')
}
```

If the [API Viewer](https://jenkinsci.github.io/job-dsl-plugin/#method/javaposse.jobdsl.dsl.helpers.publisher.PublisherContext.dependencyCheck) does not list support for a certain plugin, the dynamic DSL can be used to fill the gap.

Use the embedded API Viewer to explore the available DSL methods. If your Jenkins instance is running at http://localhost:8080, then the API viewer can be opened at http://localhost:8080/plugin/job-dsl/api-viewer/index.html.

Reference:https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Dynamic-DSL